Item Prototype that sum sent and received bits/sec - Formula : incorrect expression starting
I am struggling with something which should be basic in my mind.
I am trying to create an Item Prototype that sums the sent and received bits/sec on a port using Zabbix 6.4.
This is what I have filled out:
Name: Calculated Port throughput
Key: net.if.bandwidth[{#IFNAME}]
formula: net.if.in(ifHCInOctets.{#SNMPINDEX})+ net.if.in(ifHCOutOctets.{#SNMPINDEX})

Why am I getting a "Incorrect value for field "Formula": incorrect expression starting from "net.if.in(ifHCInOctets.{#SNMPINDEX})+ net.if.in(ifHCOutOctets.{#SNMPINDEX})" message?


Is it possible to use two predefined items and operate on them in Zabbix to create a  calculated item?

From the documentation:

Example 3 Calculating total bandwidth on eth0.
Sum of two functions:
last(//net.if.in[eth0,bytes])+last(//net.if.out[eth0,bytes])

You should refer to the standard format:

The syntax of a simple formula is:
function(/host/key,<parameter1>,<parameter2>,...)

Also, consider that:

The current host can be omitted (i.e. as in
function(//key,parameter,...))

